# A Fun(ny) Treasure Hunt

Tags: riddle, rhyme, humor, treasure-hunt

I'll send you on a treasure hunt,
Hopefully you don't mind.
The clues may not be right up front,
Maybe they are behind.

The clues you need are down below,
And hidden in plain sight.
I do not wish contention to sow,
So solve this by your might.

Tell me the secret message
To liven up your day.
It hopefully relieves your stresses,
Here at the end of May.

\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|}  
\hline
1. & 1 & 2 & 1\\
\hline
2. & 2 & 13 & 2 \\
\hline
3. & 1 & 19 & 1 \\
\hline
4. & 1 & 8 & 2 \\
\hline
5. & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
\hline
6. & 1 & 5 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Very nice rhymes!

Comment: I think I found the clues, but no idea where to go from there...

Comment: I have a hunch on what the first and second columns (not counting the one that goes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) are referring to, but I can't seem to get the third column to make sense in that context...

Comment: @GlenO I'll post a clue a little later. If you can figure out everything else, I think the last column will come to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> My imaginary friends think you have mental problems
>  (Gee, thanks)

Reasoning:

> Looking in the source code, we can find links pointing to 6 xkcd comics:
>  1. http://xkcd.com/539/
>  2. http://xkcd.com/410/
>  3. http://xkcd.com/610/
>  4. http://xkcd.com/308/
>  5. http://xkcd.com/706/
>  6. http://xkcd.com/1171/
>
>  Then we can use the grid:
>  The first column tells you which comic to look at
>  The second column tells you which panel to look at
>  The third column tells you which word to start at
>  The fourth column tells you how many works to read

So...

> The first comic gives up the single word "MY"
>  The second comic gives up the words "IMAGINARY FRIENDS" (counting hyphens as two words)
>  The third comic gives up the work "THINK"
>  The fourth comic gives up the words "YOU HAVE"
>  The fifth comic gives up the word "MENTAL"
>  And finally the sixth comic gives up the word "PROBLEMS"

Giving the final message as...

> MY IMAGINARY FRIENDS THINK YOU HAVE MENTAL PROBLEMS

Comment: Darn, I can't get the links to be spoilered... any help?

Comment: Nice, but I don't understand where you got the links. Are they somewhere hidden in the text?

Comment: @leoll2 Yep, if you click on the "edit" button in the bottom left you can see them in the plaintext

Comment: @luxmi12 Very nicely done.

Comment: @luxmi12 The links may only be visable to those that have already visited them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256941/visited-links-within-spoilers-are-not-hidden-anymore

Comment: @AggieKidd Ah that makes sense, thanks!